# XPage is forcing expires: -1 header

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have a "headless" XPage (returning JSON) and am setting the Expires header to force the browser to not request the JSON feed again for at least an hour. I have code in the AfterRenderResponse event as follows - but looking at the response headers, I see my Expires header, but also see an additional "Expires: -1" header which Domino seems to be forcing. I see this on 8.5.1 and 8.5.3 servers. Is this is known bug? Is there any way to prevent Domino from adding the expires header?

```
// Get handle to output writer - we will sender JSON text directly 
var externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
var response = externalContext.getResponse();

// set headers
response.setContentType("application/json"); 
var now = new Date(); 
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", now.getTime() + (60*60*1000));
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");

// Output it
writer.write(getJSONResponse ());
writer.endDocument();
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

What I see in the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Lotus-Domino
Date: Tue, 15 May 2012 13:17:57 GMT
**Expires: -1  <--- WHY????**
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: Tue, 15 May 2012 14:17:52 GMT
Cache-Control: public
Content-Length: 901
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change it to use the beforeRenderResponse event, the -1 expires header will disappear.

This is probably related to the afterRenderResponse event kicking in after parts of the response and thereby the -1 expires header has been created.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had tried that - and Domino still adds the extra header.

Comment: In my test it disappeared. Try setting caching options in Application Properties. I haven't tested if that impacts XAgents

Comment: Did your test include writing to the facesContact responseWriter? I find I can get rid of the Domino-generated header if I do not write anything to the response. Once I add the line: writer.write ("xxx"); Domino forces the Expires:-1 header.

Comment: Yes, I wrote to the responseWriter.

Comment: OK - I think I found the problem. When moving the code to the beforeRenderResponse, you cannot use facesContext.getResponseWriter, and instead need to get the write from the response - facesContext.getExternalContext().getWriter() Making this change, output is fine and Domino is not setting the header. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ed Schembor: ExternalContext has not a *getWriter()*-method.

Comment: [EDIT] When moving the code to the beforeRenderResponse, you cannot use facesContext.getResponseWriter, and instead need to get the writer from the response - facesContext.getResponse().getWriter() Making this change, output is fine and Domino is not setting the header. Thanks for your help!